# Symbol 'term <root>.shapeless' is missing from the classpath. This symbol is required by 'value breeze.linalg.operators.MatrixGenericOps.v1ne'

Tags: scala, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, apache-flink, scala-breeze

```
import breeze.linalg.{*, Axis, DenseVector, argmax, convert, fliplr, flipud, kron, max}
import breeze.linalg.{DenseMatrix => BDM, DenseVector => BDV}
import breeze.numerics._
import java.io.File
import java.util.{ArrayList, List}
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import breeze.linalg._
import org.apache.flink.ml.MLUtils
import org.apache.flink.ml.math.Vector

object cnn {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val svm = MLUtils.readLibSVM(env, "C:\\Users\\Kannan.b\\Desktop\\w2v\\MLP.txt")
    svm.print()
    val traintest = Splitter.trainTestSplit(svm, 0.7, true)
    val train = traintest.training
    val astroTest: DataSet[(Double, Vector)] = MLUtils.readLibSVM(env, "C:\\Users\\Kannan.b\\Desktop\\w2v\\MLP.txt")
      .map(x => (x.label, x.vector))

    val test = traintest.testing
    val model = new Sequential()
    val one = 5
    val two = 1
    val three = 3
    val four = 3
    val five = 2
    val six = 2
    model.add(new Convolution2D(one, two, three, four, five, six))
    model.add(new Activation("relu"))
    model.add(new Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(new Dense(20, 10))
    model.add(new Activation("softmax"))

    val res = model.fit(astroTest)
  }

  case class Ml(input: Double, output: Int)

    abstract class Layer {
    // Initialize variables that are shared by all layers. Note that not every variable will
    // be used by ever layer type (for example, the activation layers do not have weights).

    var layer_type: String = null

    var delta: BDM[Double] = null

    var weights: BDM[Double] = null

    var moment1: BDM[Double] = null

    var moment2: BDM[Double] = null

    // Initialize functions that are shared by all layers. Note that not every layer type will
    // use every function (for example, the activation layers do not call compute_gradient).

    def forward(forward_data: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double]

    def prev_delta(delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double]

    def compute_gradient(backward_data: BDM[Double], delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double]

    def init_conv_parameters(num_filters: Int, prev_channels: Int, filter_height: Int,
                             filter_width: Int, kind: String): BDM[Double] = {
      // Convolutional filter matrix is a vertical stack of filters. Order is that for each
      // previous channel, fill in the filters that map to the next impage map.
      val filters = BDM.zeros[Double](filter_height * num_filters * prev_channels, filter_width)
      val r = scala.util.Random
      for (j <- 0 until prev_channels) {
        for (i <- 0 until num_filters) {
          val y_index = filter_height * j + filter_height * i
          if (kind == "weights") {
            //filters(y_index until y_index + filter_height, ::) :=
              BDM.ones[Double](filter_height, filter_width).map(x => r.nextDouble - 0.5) :* .01
          } else {
            filters(y_index until y_index + filter_height, ::) :=
              BDM.zeros[Double](filter_height, filter_width)
          }
        }
      }
      filters
    }
  }

  class Sequential {

    var layers: List[Layer] = new ArrayList[Layer]

    var optimizer: Optimizer = null

    var lr: Double = .01

    var s: Double = .9

    var r: Double = .999

    var loss: String = "categorical_crossentropy"

    var metrics: String = "accuracy"

    var optimizer_type: String = "adam"

    def add(new_layer: Layer): Unit = {
      layers.add(new_layer)

      // Allows Dropout layer to be specified by user without manually adding activation function
      if (new_layer.layer_type == "Dropout") {
        layers.add(new Activation("linear"))
      }
    }

    def evaluate(train_eval: BDM[Double], labels: BDV[Double]): Unit = {
      var f = train_eval
      // Forward through topology
      for (layer <- 0 to this.layers.size - 1) {
        f = this.layers.get(layer).forward(f)
      }
      val softmax = f

      // Column in softmax with maximum value corresponds to prediction
      val predictions = argmax(softmax, Axis._1)

      // Compute proportion of labels that are correct
     val diff = predictions - convert(labels, Int)
      var count = 0
      for (i <- 0 to diff.size - 1) {
        if (diff(i) == 0) {
          count += 1
        }
        else {}
      }
      print("Train Accuracy: ")
      println(count.toDouble / diff.size.toDouble)

    }

    def get_batch(x_train: BDM[Double], y_train: BDV[Int], batch_size: Int):
    (BDM[Double], BDV[Int]) = {
      val rand = scala.util.Random
      val x_batch = BDM.zeros[Double](batch_size, x_train.cols)
      val y_batch = BDV.zeros[Int](batch_size)

      for (i <- 0 until batch_size) {
        val batch_index = rand.nextInt(x_train.rows - batch_size)
        x_batch(i, ::) := x_train(batch_index, ::)
        y_batch(i) = y_train(batch_index)
      }
      (x_batch, y_batch)
    }

    def compile(loss: String, optimizer: Optimizer, metrics: String): Unit = {
      this.optimizer = optimizer
      this.loss = loss
      this.metrics = metrics
    }

    def fit(DS: DataSet[(Double, Vector)], num_iters: Int = 1000, batch_size: Int = 16): Sequential = {

      // Grab relevant variables for optimizaiton from the optimizer object.
      val lr = this.optimizer.lr
      val s = this.optimizer.s
      val r = this.optimizer.r
      val optimizer = this.optimizer.optimizer_type
      // Convert Spark Dataframe to Breeze Dense Matrix and Dense Vector

      // Convert Spark Dataframe to Breeze Dense Matrix and Dense Vector
      // For Reference

      val xArray = DenseVector(DS.map(v => v._1).collect())
      val xArray1 = new BDV[Double](xArray.length)
      for (i <- 0 until xArray.length) {
        xArray1(i) = xArray(i)(0).asInstanceOf[Double]
      }
      val x = new BDM[Double](xArray.length, xArray(0).length)

      val x1 = for (i <- 0 until xArray.length) {
        x(i, ::) := xArray1(i).t
      }
      val yArray = DenseVector(DS.map { pair => pair._2 }.collect());
      val y = new BDV[Double](yArray.length)
      for (i <- 0 until yArray.length) {
        y(i) = yArray(i)(0).asInstanceOf[Double]
      }

      //val xArray = DS.map(v => v.input)
      //.map(v => new BDV[Double](v).collect()
      //var xArray=  BDV(DS.map{pair => pair.input }.collect());

      //val ones = DenseMatrix.ones[Double](x.rows, 1)
      val x_train = x
      val y_train = convert(y, Int)

      val class_count = this.layers.get(this.layers.size - 2).asInstanceOf[Dense].get_num_hidden

      def conditional(value: Int, seek: Int): Int = {
        if (value == seek) {
          -1
        } else {
          0
        }
      }

      val numerical_stability = .00000001
      val rand = scala.util.Random

      for (iterations <- 0 to num_iters) {

        val (x_batch, y_batch) = get_batch(x_train, y_train, batch_size)

        var f = x_batch
        // Forward
        for (layer <- 0 to this.layers.size - 1) {
          f = this.layers.get(layer).forward(f)
        }
        var softmax = f

        // Backward

        val softmax_delta = BDM.zeros[Double](batch_size, class_count)
        for (i <- 0 to softmax_delta.cols - 1) {
          softmax_delta(::, i) := softmax_delta(::, i) + convert(convert(y_batch, Int)
            .map(x => conditional(x, i)), Double)
        }
        softmax = softmax + softmax_delta
        this.layers.get(this.layers.size - 1).delta = softmax :/ batch_size.toDouble

        // Compute Errors
        for (i <- this.layers.size - 2 to 0 by -1) {
          this.layers.get(i).delta = this.layers.get(i).prev_delta(this.layers.get(i + 1).delta)
        }

        // Compute and Update Gradients
        for (i <- this.layers.size - 2 to 0 by -1) {
          if (this.layers.get(i).layer_type == "Dense" ||
            this.layers.get(i).layer_type == "Convolution2D") {
            val gradient =
              if (i == 0) {
                if (this.layers.get(i).layer_type == "Dense") {
                  this.layers.get(i).asInstanceOf[Dense].compute_gradient(x_batch,
                    this.layers.get(i + 1).delta)
                } else {
                  this.layers.get(i).asInstanceOf[Convolution2D].compute_gradient(x_batch,
                    this.layers.get(i + 1).delta)
                }
              } else {
                if (this.layers.get(i).layer_type == "Dense") {
                  this.layers.get(i).asInstanceOf[Dense].compute_gradient(this.layers.get(i - 1)
                    .asInstanceOf[Activation].hidden_layer, this.layers.get(i + 1).delta)
                } else {
                  this.layers.get(i).asInstanceOf[Convolution2D].compute_gradient(this.layers.get(i - 1)
                    .asInstanceOf[Activation].hidden_layer, this.layers.get(i + 1).delta)
                }
              }

            val layer = this.layers.get(i)

            if (optimizer == "sgd") {
              layer.weights -= lr * gradient
            }
            else if (optimizer == "momentum") {
              layer.moment1 = s * layer.moment1 + lr * gradient
              layer.weights -= layer.moment1
            }
            else if (optimizer == "adam") {
              layer.moment1 = s * layer.moment1 + (1 - s) * gradient
              layer.moment2 = r * layer.moment2 + (1 - r) * (gradient :* gradient)
              val m1_unbiased = layer.moment1 :/ (1 - (math.pow(s, iterations + 1)))
              val m2_unbiased = layer.moment2 :/ (1 - (math.pow(r, iterations + 1)))
              layer.weights -= lr * m1_unbiased :/ (sqrt(m2_unbiased) + numerical_stability)
            }
          }
        }
        if (iterations % 10 == 0) {
          evaluate(x(0 until 101, ::), y(0 until 101))
        }
      }
      //    println(evaluate(x(0 until 1000, ::), y(0 until 1000)))
      this
    }

    def printToFile(f: java.io.File)(op: java.io.PrintWriter => Unit) {
      val p = new java.io.PrintWriter(f)
      try {
        op(p)
      } finally {
        p.close()
      }
    }

    def save(name: String): Unit = {
      val model = this
      var layers: Array[String] = new Array[String](model.layers.size)
      var weights: List[BDM[Double]] = new ArrayList[BDM[Double]]

      for (i <- 0 until model.layers.size) {
        layers(i) = model.layers.get(i).layer_type
        if (model.layers.get(i).layer_type == "Dense" || model.layers.get(i).layer_type ==
          "Convolution2D") {
          weights.add(model.layers.get(i).weights)
        } else {}
      }

      val dir = new File(name)
      dir.mkdir()

      this.printToFile(new File(name + "/layers.txt")) {
        p => layers.foreach(p.println)
      }

      var weights_index = 0
      for (i <- 0 until model.layers.size) {
        if (model.layers.get(i).layer_type == "Dense" || model.layers.get(i).layer_type ==
          "Convolution2D") {
          breeze.linalg.csvwrite(new File(name + "/weights" + i.toString),
            weights.get(weights_index))
          weights_index += 1
        }
      }
    }


  }

  class Model() {

    def load(name: String): Sequential = {
      val seq: Sequential = new Sequential()
      val lines = scala.io.Source.fromFile(name + "/layers.txt").mkString.split("\n")

      for (i <- 0 until lines.length) {
        if (lines(i) == "Convolution2D") {
          seq.add(new Convolution2D(8, 1, 3, 3, 28, 28))
          seq.layers.get(i).weights = breeze.linalg.csvread(new File(
            name + "/weights" + i.toString))
        }
        if (lines(i) == "Dense") {
          seq.add(new Dense(6272, 10))
          seq.layers.get(i).weights = breeze.linalg.csvread(new File(name + "/weights" + i.toString))
        }
        if (lines(i) == "Activation" && i == 1) {
          seq.add(new Activation("relu"))
        }
        if (lines(i) == "Activation" && i == 3) {
          seq.add(new Activation("softmax"))
        }
      }
      seq
    }
  }

  class Dense(input_shape: Int, num_hidden: Int) extends Layer {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    this.weights = BDM.ones[Double](input_shape, num_hidden).map(x => r.nextDouble - 0.5) :* .01
    this.moment1 = BDM.zeros[Double](input_shape, num_hidden)
    this.moment2 = BDM.zeros[Double](input_shape, num_hidden)
    var hidden_layer: BDM[Double] = null
    this.delta = null
    this.layer_type = "Dense"

    def get_num_hidden: Int = num_hidden

    def get_input_shape: Int = input_shape

    override def forward(forward_data: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      // Breeze's matrix multiplication syntax allows us to simply use *
      hidden_layer = forward_data * weights
      hidden_layer
    }

    override def prev_delta(delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      delta * weights.t
    }

    override def compute_gradient(backward_data: BDM[Double], delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      backward_data.t * delta
    }
  }

  class Dropout(proportion: Double) extends Layer {
    val r = scala.util.Random
    this.layer_type = "Dropout"


    override def forward(forward_data: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      // May need to do something fancy at inference time
      forward_data.map(x => if (r.nextDouble < proportion) {
        0
      } else {
        x
      })
    }

    override def prev_delta(delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      delta
    }

    override def compute_gradient(backward_data: BDM[Double], delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      println("MAJOR ERROR - ACTIVATION LAYER SHOULD NOT COMPUTE GRADIENT")
      backward_data
    }

  }

  class Convolution2D(
                       num_filters: Int, // Number of filters in convolutional layer
                       prev_channels: Int, // Number of filters in previous layer
                       filter_height: Int, // Height of filters in this convoltional layer
                       filter_width: Int, // Width of filters in this convolutional layer
                       img_height: Int, // Height of filter map input to this layer
                       img_width: Int // Width of filter map input to this layer
                     ) extends Layer {
    this.layer_type = "Convolution2D"
    this.weights = init_conv_parameters(num_filters,
      prev_channels, filter_height, filter_width, "weights")
    this.moment1 = init_conv_parameters(num_filters,
      prev_channels, filter_height, filter_width, "moment")
    this.moment2 = init_conv_parameters(num_filters,
      prev_channels, filter_height, filter_width, "moment")
    this.delta = null
    val len = img_height * img_width

    def convolution(image: BDM[Double], filter: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      val image_height = image.rows
      val image_width = image.cols
      val local_filter_height = filter.rows
      val local_filter_width = filter.cols
      val padded = BDM.zeros[Double](image_height + 2 * (filter_height / 2),
        image_width + 2 * (filter_width / 2))
      for (i <- 0 until image_height) {
        for (j <- 0 until image_width) {
          padded(i + (filter_height / 2), j + (filter_height / 2)) = image(i, j)
        }
      }
      val convolved = BDM.zeros[Double](image_height - local_filter_height + 1 + 2 *
        (filter_height / 2), image_width - local_filter_width + 1 + 2 * (filter_width / 2))
      for (i <- 0 until convolved.rows) {
        for (j <- 0 until convolved.cols) {
          var aggregate = 0.0
          for (k <- 0 until local_filter_height) {
            for (l <- 0 until local_filter_width) {
              aggregate += padded(i + k, j + l) * filter(k, l)
            }
          }
          convolved(i, j) = aggregate
        }
      }
      convolved
    }

    override def forward(input_data: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      val outputs = BDM.zeros[Double](input_data.rows, img_height * img_width *
        num_filters * prev_channels)
      for (i <- 0 until input_data.rows) {
        for (j <- 0 until prev_channels) {
          for (k <- 0 until prev_channels) {
            for (l <- 0 until num_filters) {
              val index1 = l * len + k * len
              val index2 = (l + 1) * len + k * len
              val data_index1 = j * len
              val data_index2 = (j + 1) * len
              val filter_index = k * filter_height + l * filter_height
              val img = input_data(i, data_index1 until data_index2).t.toDenseMatrix
                .reshape(img_height, img_width)
              val fil = weights(filter_index until (filter_index + filter_height), ::)
              outputs(i, index1 until index2) := convolution(img, fil)
                .reshape(1, img_height * img_width).toDenseVector.t
            }
          }
        }
      }
      outputs
    }

    override def prev_delta(delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      val output_delta = BDM.zeros[Double](delta.rows, delta.cols / num_filters)
      for (i <- 0 until delta.rows) {
        for (j <- 0 until prev_channels) {
          for (k <- 0 until num_filters) {
            val filter_index = filter_height * j + filter_height * k
            val x_index = j * len + k * len
            val img = delta(i, x_index until x_index + len).t.toDenseMatrix
              .reshape(img_height, img_width)
            val filter = flipud(fliplr(weights(filter_index until filter_index + filter_height, ::)))
            val x_output = j * len
            output_delta(i, x_output until x_output + len) +=
              convolution(img, filter).reshape(1, img_height * img_width).toDenseVector.t
          }
        }
      }
      output_delta :/ num_filters.toDouble
    }

    override def compute_gradient(backward_data: BDM[Double], delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      val gradient = BDM.zeros[Double](filter_height * num_filters * prev_channels, filter_width)
      for (i <- 0 until backward_data.rows) {
        for (j <- 0 until prev_channels) {
          for (k <- 0 until num_filters) {
            val y_index = filter_height * j + filter_height * k
            val data_index = prev_channels * j
            val delta_index = k * len
            gradient(y_index until y_index + filter_height, ::) +=
              convolution(backward_data(i, data_index until (data_index + len)).t.toDenseMatrix.
                reshape(img_height, img_width), delta(i, delta_index until (delta_index + len)).
                t.toDenseMatrix.reshape(img_height, img_width))
          }
        }
      }
      gradient :/ backward_data.rows.toDouble
    }
  }

  class MaxPooling2D(pool_height: Int, pool_width: Int, pool_stride_x: Int, pool_stride_y: Int,
                     prev_channels: Int, num_filters: Int, img_height: Int, img_width: Int) extends Layer {
    this.layer_type = "MaxPooling2D"
    val len = img_height * img_width

    override def forward(input_data: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      val outputs = BDM.zeros[Double](input_data.rows, (img_height * img_width *
        prev_channels) / (pool_width * pool_height))
      for (i <- 0 until input_data.rows) {
        for (j <- 0 until prev_channels) {
          val img = input_data(i, j * len until (j + 1) * len).t.toDenseMatrix
            .reshape(img_height, img_width).t
          for (k <- 0 until img_height by pool_stride_y) {
            for (l <- 0 until img_width by pool_stride_x) {
              outputs(i, j * img_height / pool_height * img_width / pool_width +
                k / pool_stride_y * img_width / pool_stride_x + l / pool_stride_x) =
                max(img(k until k + pool_height, l until l + pool_width))
            }
          }
        }
      }
      outputs
    }

    override def prev_delta(delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      val output_delta = BDM.zeros[Double](delta.rows, len * prev_channels)
      for (i <- 0 until delta.rows) {
        for (j <- 0 until prev_channels) {
          val x_index = j * img_height / pool_height * img_width / pool_width
          val img = delta(i, x_index until x_index + img_height / pool_height *
            img_width / pool_width).t.toDenseMatrix.reshape(img_height / pool_height,
            img_width / pool_width)
          val x_output = j * len
          output_delta(i, x_output until x_output + len) :=
            kron(img, BDM.ones[Double](pool_height, pool_width)).reshape(1,
              img_height * img_width).toDenseVector.t
        }
      }
      output_delta
    }

    override def compute_gradient(backward_data: BDM[Double], delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      println("MAJOR ERROR - POOLING LAYER SHOULD NOT COMPUTE GRADIENT")
      backward_data
    }
  }

  class Optimizer() {
    var lr: Double = 0.01
    var s: Double = 0.9
    var r: Double = 0.999
    var optimizer_type: String = "adam"

    def adam(lr: Double = 0.01, s: Double = 0.9, r: Double = 0.999): Optimizer = {
      this.lr = lr
      this.s = s
      this.r = r
      this.optimizer_type = "adam"
      this
    }

    def momentum(lr: Double = 0.01, s: Double = 0.9): Optimizer = {
      this.lr = lr
      this.s = s
      this.optimizer_type = "momentum"
      this
    }

    def SGD(lr: Double = 0.01): Optimizer = {
      this.lr = lr
      this.optimizer_type = "sgd"
      this
    }
  }

  class Activation(var kind: String) extends Layer {
    this.layer_type = "Activation"
    var hidden_layer: BDM[Double] = null
    this.delta = null
    var output_softmax: BDM[Double] = null

    override def forward(input_data: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {

      if (kind == "relu") {
        hidden_layer = input_data.map(x => max(0.0, x))
        hidden_layer
      }

      else if (kind == "linear") {
        hidden_layer = input_data
        hidden_layer
      }

      else if (kind == "softmax") {
        val softmax = exp(input_data)
        val divisor = breeze.linalg.sum(softmax(*, ::))
        for (i <- 0 to softmax.cols - 1) {
          softmax(::, i) := softmax(::, i) :/ divisor
        }
        softmax
      }

      else {
        println("MAJOR ERROR1")
        input_data
      }
    }

    def relu_grad(value: Double): Double = {
      if (value <= 0) {
        0
      } else {
        1
      }
    }

    override def prev_delta(delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      if (kind == "relu") {
        delta :* hidden_layer.map(relu_grad)
        delta
      }
      else if (kind == "linear") {
        delta
      }
      else {
        println("MAJOR ERROR2")
        delta
      }
    }

    override def compute_gradient(backward_data: BDM[Double], delta: BDM[Double]): BDM[Double] = {
      println("MAJOR ERROR - ACTIVATION LAYER SHOULD NOT COMPUTE GRADIENT")
      backward_data
    }
  }
```

Note: This is the Scala CNN code that we are trying to execute on Apache Flink but it throws the below error

Error:(143, 67) Symbol 'term .shapeless' is missing from the classpath.
This symbol is required by 'value breeze.linalg.operators.MatrixGenericOps.v1ne'.
Make sure that term shapeless is in your classpath and check for conflicting dependencies with `-Ylog-classpath`.
A full rebuild may help if 'MatrixGenericOps.class' was compiled against an incompatible version of .
              BDM.ones[Double](filter_height, filter_width).map(x => r.nextDouble - 0.5) :* .01

Comment: Are you sure that Shapeless is in your classpath? Did you try to add JAR file to classpath? http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/chuusai/shapeless_2.12/2.3.3/shapeless_2.12-2.3.3.jar

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin Thank You!!!